Early exercise with multiple dividends
I am wondering how early exercise conditions work on multiple dividends. Say a stock pays 4 dividends in a year. We are 1 day before the first ex-div date and long an ITM Call and ITM put in an expiry which includes the 4 dividends. How do our calculations change from a basic 1 dividend example to account for the next 3 dividends?
